# Adding an extra parenthesis into a method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parentheses

Whenever I go through JavaScript code, I see a method that haves a pair of extra parentheses.

For example:

```
if( (typeOf VariableName) === "function" )
```

or

```
alert(("Hello World"))
```

What does these do, and why are they needed?

Comment: The examples you gave would even work without extra `()`. Generally `IIFE` functions are enclosed inside `()`

Comment: In the examples you posted they are not needed. Use `if (typeof VariableName === 'function')`  and `alert('Hello World')`

Comment: for your first example, consider `if( typeof (VariableName === "function"))` this will resolve to `if("boolean")` and because "boolean" is a non falsy value this will always return true no matter what variableName is... sometimes you are not sure in what order the operators are applied, so you are explicit about it...

Comment: These extra parenthesis can be used for code clarity.  (Not applicable in the examples you show, but perhaps there are some more complex order-of-operations that need clarified.)

Answer (score 3):

In JS, parentheses used for multiple purposes.

- Grouping operator (like in mathematical expressions)
- Function call (if placed after an identifier)
- Several statements require them

The examples you've provided are of type where they act as grouping operators.

In your scenario, they aren't needed, both examples would work without them as well.

However, there are cases when you have to use additional parens, for example:

- Forcing a statement into expression context:

  ```
  function(){}() //This is evaluated like a function declaration, SyntaxError

  (function(){})() //Works

  x => {'x': x} //Returns undefined

  x => ({'x': x}) //Returns the object
  ```
- Changing the evaluation order:

  ```
  1+2*3 //7

  (1+2)*3 //9
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Those particular examples would work the same without the extra parenthesis.

```js
const x = () => {};

if( (typeof x) === "function" ) {
  console.log('yup');
}

if(typeof x === "function") {
  console.log('yup');
}

alert("Hello World")
```

One use case for adding additional parentheses is to overcome [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

```js
console.log(3 + 4 * 5); // 3 + 20
console.log((3 + 4) * 5); // 7 * 5
```

Another example where adding additional parenthesis around a function is used is to invoke the function in the same place it's defined in (commonly known as an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)):

```js
function notInvoked() {
  console.log('this does not happen');
}

(function invoked() {
  console.log('this happens');
})(); // Note: an IIFE also requires a pair of () before or after the last parenthesis so that the function is actually invoked
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember [[BODMAS]](https://byjus.com/maths/bodmas-rule/) Rule,

Which has set of rules of arithmetic precedence for the way microprocessor do arithmetic decisions.

So highest precedence in Rule is bracket, We can set statements in bracket where end results might will affect because of **Division Multipication Addition Subtraction [ DMAS ]** precedences. (which in many cases are overlooked because of complexities of statements )